# Why ngModel is not updating the value for the first time?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

Why ng-Model value is not showing the updated value

Please check my code below

JS

```
$scope.test='xx';
$scope.testfunc=function (a) {   
  alert(a);
 }
```

HTML

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="test" ng-click="testfunc(test)" value="aaa"/>
```

When i tap on radio, i should get the alert message "aaa" but i am getting message"xx" .

Can anyone tell me where i went wrong

Answer (score 2):

The value of the radio is changed by the model.

Originaly the radio has the value "aaa", then after angular "boots", the value of the rasio is changed to xx, if you inspect the element using the browser developer tools(chrome, firefox, or IE10 and up), you should see it.

your radio is like this after angular finishes linking(booting)

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="test" ng-click="testfunc(test)" value="xx"/>
```

Comment: What is the solution for this

Comment: Set $scope.test='aaa' or remove ng-model directive from your input field. What is your use case?

Comment: use "ng-change" instead of ng-click

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you bind the scope.text='xx'; this has nothing to do with value='aaa'

ng-model=test is referencing the $scope.test.

If you want it to be 'aaa' you need to bind it to scope.test, which you pass into the function in the html as the param.

Solution would be to pass it as a param:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="test" ng-click="testfunc('xx')" value="xx"/>
```

or with jQuery:

```
$scope.test = $('input:radio').val();
```

Vanilla JS

```
$scope.test = document.querySelectorAll('input:radio');
```

Comment: Can you share any example if you have